# How to break while loop Java

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, runtime-error

At the main class:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException at this line char character = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

and

```
input mismatched at line: double pay=sc.nextDouble();
```

The problem occurs because I didn't break my while loop. The answer has been updated

The input at Codezinger;

```
5  
=  
- 0.70  
- 2.40   
- 1.20   
+ 20.00   
3  
- 5.00   
- 0.50    
=    
0
```

The main class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMyPrintCard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        int N = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        do {
            System.out.println("Case #" + x + ":");
            MyPrintCard c1 = new MyPrintCard(); 

            for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
                char character = sc.next().charAt(0); // char input =,+,- // PROBLEM HERE
                if (character == '=' ) {
                    System.out.println("RM" + df.format(c1.getBalance()));
                } else if (character == '+') {      
                    double topup = sc.nextDouble();
                    c1.topupCard(topup);
                } else if (character == '-') {
                    double pay = sc.nextDouble(); // PROBLEM HERE
                    c1.payService(pay);             
                }   
            } //end for

            x++;
        } while (N != 0);   
    }
}
```

The class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MyPrintCard {
    private double balance; //declare
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    
    MyPrintCard() { //constructor initialized
        balance = 10.00;        
    }
    
    //getter
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    
    public void topupCard(double amt) {
        balance += amt;
        System.out.println("RM" + df.format(balance));          
    }
    
    public void payService(double amt) {    
        if (balance > 5) {
            balance -= amt;
            System.out.println("RM" + df.format(balance));                  
        } else      
            System.out.println("invalid");
    }   
}
```

The correct answer for the main class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMyPrintCard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        int N = sc.nextInt();
    
        while (N != 0) {
            System.out.println("Case #" + x + ":");
            MyPrintCard c1 = new MyPrintCard(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                char character = sc.next().charAt(0); // for the character input, =,+,-
                if (character == '=' ) {
                    System.out.println("RM" + df.format(c1.getBalance()));
                } else if (character == '+') {      
                    double topup = sc.nextDouble();
                    c1.topupCard(topup);
                } else if (character == '-') {
                    double pay = sc.nextDouble();
                    c1.payService(pay);
                }   
            } //end for

            N = sc.nextInt();
            x++;
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Moat likely input provided by codezinger is not what your code expects.

Comment: i have add the sample input above, it only ask for the character and double number

Comment: So now you can run your code in eclipse with that input and use debugger to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're either lying or you're no good at testing. For example, the very example input you pasted wouldn't work, even in eclipse.

Your do/while loop **runs forever**. It has no stop condition at all: No break, and the `while` condition of `N != 0` will never fail to be `true`, as you never modify `N`. Your error is that you're supposed to re-read N at the top of that `do` loop, instead of *before* it. Every segment in the input starts with a number indicating how many operations follow (with `0` being used to terminate the app). You only read the first such number.

Fix that and this code will work fine... probably, there is one more small issue:

Separately, that `sc.nextLine()` is not useful to this code and dangerous in that it can mess with reading the input depending on precisely how codezinger is providing it to you. Note that a very large amount of tutorials on scanner and keyboard input out there, including most SO answers, erroneously suggesting you run `sc.nextLine()` after every input. Do not do this<sup>1</sup>.

1. Not relevant to this question, but I better back up such a statement: If you want keyboard input where hitting enter separates input, instead configure the scanner properly (use `scanner.useDelimiter("\\R")`, call `scanner.next()` to get a line of text, and don't ever call `.nextLine()`). This is much simpler (no need to remember to toss those pointless `nextLine()` in there) can read blank input, and will not fail if the user tries to separate things with spaces instead of newlines.

Comment: Nope it runs , i share the picture above that my code runs in eclipse

Comment: i cant seem to understand how should I break the loop

Comment: okay i got it. i already fix my code, thank you